# Data import issue (HTTP Status 404) using solr and tomcat6

Tags: mysql, solr, tomcat6, ubuntu-12.10

Version list

- solr 4.2.0
- ubuntu 12.10
- tomcat 6
- sql 5.5.29

---

i successfully setup solr on my server and can access solr admin page using this link

```
http://localhost:8080/solr
```

the problem is on dataimport i see http status 404 error on trying dataimport...

description :The requested resource (/solr/dataimport) is not available.

```
 http://localhost:8080/solr/dataimport
```

here is my directory structure

> root@web:~/solr-4.2.0/example/solr/collection1/conf# ls
>
> admin-extra.html              mapping-FoldToASCII.txt
>   stopwords.txt admin-extra.menu-bottom.html 
>   mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt  synonyms.txt admin-extra.menu-top.html
>   protwords.txt                update-script.js currency.xml
>   schema.xml                   velocity data-config.xml
>   scripts.conf                 xslt elevate.xml
>   solrconfig.xml lang                          spellings.txt
>
> root@ web:~/solr-4.2.0/example/lib# ls
>
> jetty-continuation-8.1.8.v20121106.jar 
>   jetty-server-8.1.8.v20121106.jar jetty-deploy-8.1.8.v20121106.jar
>   jetty-servlet-8.1.8.v20121106.jar jetty-http-8.1.8.v20121106.jar
>   jetty-util-8.1.8.v20121106.jar jetty-io-8.1.8.v20121106.jar
>   jetty-webapp-8.1.8.v20121106.jar jetty-jmx-8.1.8.v20121106.jar
>   jetty-xml-8.1.8.v20121106.jar jetty-security-8.1.8.v20121106.jar
>   servlet-api-3.0.jar
>
> root@ web:~/solr-4.2.0/dist# ls -l 
>   total 20716
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 17359734 Mar  7 06:32 solr-4.2.0.war
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    16714 Mar  7 06:31 solr-analysis-extras-4.2.0.jar
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    29896 Mar  7 06:32 solr-cell-4.2.0.jar
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    50435 Mar  7 06:31 solr-clustering-4.2.0.jar
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2106321 Mar  7 06:32 solr-core-4.2.0.jar
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   217076 Mar  7 06:31 solr-dataimporthandler-4.2.0.jar
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    31134 Mar  7 06:31 solr-dataimporthandler-extras-4.2.0.jar
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   766460 Mar  7 06:32 solr-langid-4.2.0.jar
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   392357 Mar  7 06:32 solr-solrj-4.2.0.jar
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   149825 Mar  7 06:31 solr-test-framework-4.2.0.jar
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    38743 Mar  7 06:32 solr-uima-4.2.0.jar
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    20286 Mar  7 06:32 solr-velocity-4.2.0.jar drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Jun 20 17:59 solrj-lib drwxr-xr-x 4
>   root root     4096 Jun 20 17:59 test-framework
>
> root@ web:~/solr-4.2.0/contrib# ls -l 
>   total 28 drwxr-xr-x 4 root root
>   4096 Mar  7 06:33 analysis-extras drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun 20
>   17:59 clustering drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun 20 17:59
>   dataimporthandler drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun 20 17:59 extraction
>   drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun 20 17:59 langid drwxr-xr-x 4 root root
>   4096 Mar  7 06:33 uima drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun 20 17:59
>   velocity
>
> root@web:~/solr-4.2.0/example/solr# ls -l
>    total 20
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2473 Oct 17  2012 README.txt drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 17  2012 bin drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun 20 17:59
>   collection1
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2222 Jun 25 15:44 solr.xml
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  501 Oct 17  2012 zoo.cfg

In the **solarconfig.xml** file located in the /solr-4.2.0/example/solr/collection1/conf added dataimport lib path

```
<lib dir="../../../../../contrib/dataimporthandler/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="../../../../contrib/extraction/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="../../../../dist/" regex="solr-cell-\d.*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="../../../../contrib/clustering/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="../../../../dist/" regex="solr-clustering-\d.*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="../../../../contrib/langid/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="../../../../dist/" regex="solr-langid-\d.*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="../../../../contrib/velocity/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="../../../../dist/" regex="solr-velocity-\d.*\.jar" />
<lib dir="../../../../dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-\d.*\.jar" />
```

i have tried changing the path to different directories but still the same response..

in the same **solarconfig.xml** file defined this

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
      <lst name="datasource">
         <str name="driver">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</str>
         <str name="url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web</str>
         <str name="user">username</str>
         <str name="password">password</str>
      </lst>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

added my own field names in the **schema.xml** file under other fields names...

```
<field name="solr_field1" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="solr_field2" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />

 <field name="solr_field3" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="solr_field4" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />

<field name="solr_field5" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="solr_field6" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="solr_field7" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="solr_field8" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="solr_field9" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="solr_field10" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="solr_field11" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="solr_field12" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
```

and these afterword these fields as well...

```
<copyField source="contact_name" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="contact_email" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="business_name" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="city" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="state" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="zip_code" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="phone" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="website" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="address" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="major_division" dest="text"/>
```

created the **data-config.xml** file in the same directory and added the following lines

```
<dataConfig>
 <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web" user="username" password="password"/>
 <document>
     <entity name="id " query="select * from business">
        <field column="id" name="solr_field1"/>
        <field column="metro_id" name="solr_field2"/>
        <field column="contact_name" name="solr_field3"/>
        <field column="contact_email" name="solr_field4"/>
        <field column="business_name" name="solr_field5"/>
        <field column="city" name="solr_field6"/>
        <field column="state" name="solr_field7"/>
        <field column="zip_code" name="solr_field8"/>
        <field column="phone" name="solr_field9"/>
        <field column="website" name="solr_field10"/>
        <field column="address" name="solr_field11"/>
        <field column="major_division" name="solr_field12"/>
     </entity>
 </document>
</dataConfig>
```

added **sharedLib="../lib"** 
 in **solr.xml** file

```
<solr persistent="true" sharedLib="../lib">
  <cores adminPath="/admin/cores" defaultCoreName="collection1" host="${host:}" hostPort="${jetty.port:}" hostContext="${hostContext:}" zkClientTimeout="${zkClientTimeout:15000}">
    <core name="collection1" instanceDir="collection1" />
  </cores>
</solr>
```

any help as to how i can make the solr recognise the dataimport would be much appreciated thankyou ...

Comment: Are you running jetty or Tomcat ? shouldn't the port be 8983 ??

Comment: we are using Tomcat. How to check for correct port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same error. The possible solution is

I have added following lines of code in solrconfig.xml file

```
<lib dir="../../../contrib/dataimporthandler/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="apache-solr-dataimporthandler-\d.*\.jar" />
```

make sure your apache-solr-dataimporthandler-4.0.jar and apache-solr-dataimporthandler-extras-4.0.jar files in the dist folder and it's in correct path.

don't forget to restart the tomcat server.

For more detail check the following Question link.

[DIH(Data Import Handler) for xml files is not working in Solr4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629955/dihdata-import-handler-for-xml-files-is-not-working-in-solr4)

Other thing is you are using the Tomcat so your port number is 8080. not 8983.