# HTTP Status 500 error - Installing Solr 4.6.1 with Tomcat 8 on Ubuntu 13

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, solr

I want to install solr-4.6.1 with tomcat 8.0.3 on Ubuntu Desktop 13.10, but Solr can't be started.

I've followed these steps:

#### For Tomcat

1. I download apache-tomcat-8.0.3.tar.gz
2. Extracted the files to ~/Desktop/Tomcat8
3. Edited the .bashrc file and added the line export CATALINA_HOME=~/Desktop/Tomcat8
4. Created a file named setenv.sh in ~/Desktop/Tomcat8/bin with content

> JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
>   
>   I Tested the Tomcat installation by browsing to

```
http://localhost:8080
```

It works fine and displays the Tomcat home page.

#### For Solr

1. I downloaded solr-4.6.1.tgz
2. Extracted the files to ~/Desktop/solr-4.6.1
3. Copied all the contents in ~/Desktop/solr-4.6.1/example/solr/ to ~/Desktop/Solr/
4. Copied all the jar-files in ~/Desktop/solr-4.6.1/example/lib/ext to ~/Desktop/Tomcat8/lib/
5. Copied solr.war from ~/Desktop/solr-4.6.1/example/webapps to ~/Desktop/Tomcat8/webapps/
6. Edited the “~/Desktop/Tomcat8/webapps/solr/WEB-INF/web.xml file, uncommented the env-entry section and replaced /put/your/solr/home/here with ~/Desktop/Solr
7. Edited ~/Desktop/Tomcat8/bin/setenv.sh and added the line

> JAVA_OPTS="-Dsolr.solr.home=~/Desktop/Solr"
>
> #### The Problem

When I navigate to

```
http://localhost:8080/solr
```

the browser displays the following error

```
HTTP Status 500 - {msg=SolrCore 'collection1' is not available
due to init failure: Could not load config file
/home/handosa/~/Desktop/Solr/collection1/solrconfig.xml,
trace=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: SolrCore 'collection1'
is not available due to init failure: Could not load config file 
/home/handosa/~/Desktop/Solr/collection1/solrconfig.xml
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:823)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:301)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:201)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load config file
/home/handosa/~/Desktop/Solr/collection1/solrconfig.xml at
org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:530)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:597)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:251)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:243)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) ... 3 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or 
'/home/handosa/~/Desktop/Solr/collection1/conf'
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openResource(SolrResourceLoader.java:342)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openConfig(SolrResourceLoader.java:288)
at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:116) at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:86)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.<init>(SolrConfig.java:139)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:527) ... 9 more ,code=500}
```

Am I missing something?

#### Edit

It seems like the whole problem was with the use of the path ~/Desktop/Solr.
So, instead I used /home/handosa/Desktop/Solr and everything now works fine!

Comment: Flagged to be moved, this question is about application software configuration on a server, not programming

Comment: Please refer to this [Link][1]  probably it will resolve your issue.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629955/dihdata-import-handler-for-xml-files-is-not-working-in-solr4/14630625#14630625